# Grails: when does grails end to upload?

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to have an event which tell me when does grails end to upload.
Either it can be some code scope which is actually the end of the server upload.

The issue that i'm trying to retrieve the list of plugins, I have the code which making it, but it have to be when the server is uploaded completely.
I tried to make it int the 'init()' function and it not a good place to make it.

Any other suggestions ?

The code that i'm trying the run:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().applicationContext.getBean('pluginManager').allPlugins.each {plugin ->
  println "${plugin.name} - ${plugin.version}" }
```

Comment: Can you post your code snippet which might make things more clear??

Comment: I edited the original post

Comment: You should put this into bootStrap.groovy init method. This just run before grails application comes up. Are you trying the same?

Comment: Yes, and it's not working, wither in the start or in the end of it.

Comment: Is there any other way to get this info ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mock request: This will give you list of all plugin which are used in the application (Will also include services, controller plugins)

```
def applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext)
def webRequest = grails.util.GrailsWebUtil.bindMockWebRequest(applicationContext)

webRequest.applicationContext.getBean('pluginManager').allPlugins.each {plugin ->
     println "${plugin.name} - ${plugin.version}"
}
```

Output:

```
logging - 2.2.2
core - 2.2.2
pluginConfig - 0.1.5
i18n - 2.2.2
urlMappings - 2.2.2
groovyPages - 2.2.2
controllers - 2.2.2
webappcore - 5.30.103
codenarc - 0.17
rendering - 0.4.3
buildInfo - 1.2.3
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Currently i'm inside the bootstrap.groovy class, what can i put instead of 'servletContext' variable (first line)?

Comment: Put this code inside init() method this should work. After putting the necessary imports. In this method servletContext is available. def init = { servletContext ->}